# I have two arrays and I want to pair the array elements of the arrays which of sizes are not equal

Tags: javascript, arrays

This the code that i wrote

```
<script>
    var jobs = ['fault 1','fault 2','fault 3','fault 4','fault 5'];
    var  assistant =['John :','Martin :','lovemore :'];
    
    var langKeys = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
    var job = jobs[i];
    langKeys[job] = assistant[i];
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(langKeys));
    
    </script>
```

the output:

```
   {"fault 1":"John :","fault 2":"Martin :","fault 3":"lovemore :"}
```

fault 4 and fault 5 remained unassinged to an assistant

```
the desired output
        
     {"fault 1":"John :","fault 2":"Martin :","fault 3":"lovemore :","fault 4":"John :","fault 5":"Martin:"}
```

i would like the jobs to be continuously assigned to a technician

Comment: If you `console.log(assistant[i])` you will see `undefined` value because you try to use same `length` of jobs (4) on assistant array `length` (2)

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comment you need to restart `index` of `assistant` to start from the first value like:

```js
const jobs = ['fault 1', 'fault 2', 'fault 3', 'fault 4', 'fault 5'];
const assistant = ['John :', 'Martin :', 'lovemore :'];
const assistantLenght = assistant.length;
let assistantIndex = 0;
const langKeys = {};
for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
  var job = jobs[i];
  langKeys[job] = assistant[assistantIndex];
  assistantIndex++
  if (assistantIndex >= assistantLenght) {
    assistantIndex = 0;
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(langKeys));
```